# Scrapy 4xx/5xx error handling

Tags: python, scrapy

We're building a distributed system that uses Amazon's SQS to dispatch messages to workers that run scrapy spiders based on the messages' contents.

We (obviously) only want to remove a message from the queue if its corresponding spider has been run successfully, i.e. without encountering 4xx/5xx responses.

What I'd like to do is hook into scrapy's `signals` API to fire a callback that deletes the message from the queue when the spider's closed successfully, but I'm not sure whether that's actually the semantics of `signals.spider_closed` (as opposed to "this spider has closed for literally any reason.")

It's also not clear (at least to me) whether `signals.spider_error` is fired when encountering an HTTP error code, or only when a Python error is raised from within the spider.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use one crawler one spider or one crawler multiple spiders setup? If the former then you can check `downloader/request_count`, `downloader/response_count`, `downloader/response_status_count/200` values in a crawler `stats` and decide what to do.

Answer (score 0):

`signals.spider_error` is raised when a Python error occurs during the spider-crawl process. If the error occurs in the `spider_closed` signal handler then `spider_error` is not raised.

A basic approach would be to have a signal handler extension which will register to the `spider_closed` and `spider_error` events to handle the statuses -- do not remove the URL from the queue if it contains a status higher than 399 for example.

Then in these handler methods you can utilize the stats collected by the spider to see if it was OK or not:

```
class SignalHandler(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls,crawler):
        ext = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_error, signal=signals.spider_error)
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return ext

    def spider_error(self, failure, response, spider):
        print "Error on {0}, traceback: {1}".format(response.url, failure.getTraceback())

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        if spider.crawler.stats.get_value('downloader/response_status_count/200') == spider.crawler.stats.get_value('downloader/response_count'):
            # OK, all went fine
        if spider.crawler.stats.get_value('downloader/response_status_count/404') != 0 or spider.crawler.stats.get_value('downloader/response_status_count/503') != 0:
            # something went wrong
```

And of course do not forget to add your `SignalHandler` in the `settings.py`:

```
EXTENSIONS = {'myproject.extensions.signal_handler.SignalHandler': 599,}
```

There is another way of course which requires a bit more coding:

You could handle the status codes yourself with the `handle_httpstatus_list` parameter of your spider. This allows your spider to handle a list of HTTP status which would be ignored per default.

Summarizing an approach would be to handle the statuses you are interested in in your spider and collect them into a `set`.

This would be the spider:

```
class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "somespider"

    start_urls = {"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308231/liferay-6-2-lar-import-no-journalfolder-exists-with-the-primary-key-2"}

    handle_httpstatus_list = [404, 503]

    encountered = set()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.encountered.add(response.status)
        # parse the response
```

This would be the extension's new method:

```
def spider_closed(self, spider):
    if 404 in spider.encountered:
        # handle 404
```